# VB.NET - Export hidden form as application.

Tags: vb.net, compiler-construction, export, builder

It is possible to export one hidden form as a fully application including icon?

Form example I have two forms, the main one with one button and the hidden one with a message box on loading event. What I want is after the button from first form is pressed the hidden from (form2) to be built as a standalone application in a path selected by me with an icon from a selected path or from resources.

If this is impossible I heard about one method where you first create an application, then you combine the code from something1.vb and something2.vb, then you can use them to compile in another application.

Sorry for this bad explained request. Thank you so much!

Comment: The answer is yes, but you have a bit to learn first, See the example provided in the documentation for the [CodeDomProvider Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

No. It´s not possible to compile code at runtime - if I understood what you need.
You can at maximum:

1 - Create an EXE application and ZIP it.

2 - In your 1st form, unzip the application into a folder.

But certainly you will have troubles with antivirus and, in the best situation, in your unziped application since it wasn´t correctly installed.

Comment: No, you're not right. Here is a video with this kind of actions that I want to do. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-M0Yf1F1pE But I guess he imported one exe in another.

Comment: Imported one EXE into another? You asked for EXPORT an EXE from other... Anyway, I will see what you want to do.

Comment: You´re wrong. This app simply LOCK ANY OTHER APP (by encript it, for instance) and, after a password given, it decripts the EXE to its original state. Anyway, it may be done without any encryption, just changing the EXE header of any application and restoring it to its original. BUT, supposing you WANT TO IMPORT AN EXE into your application, it could be done at BUILD TIME (as a byte array for instance), not RUNTIME - and again, try to rewrite it in another place will fire antivirus and antimalware.

Comment: You have right, but not at all. With this app you import one executable into that locker. Look at this video how this guy bypass the security and found a way to extract the imported executable: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jjE6flWQgPY Also look at the first video that I gave you and see how that software built another software with those settings.  Also I request help for this problem here: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1036827/Export-Build-one-Form-as-Executable And you can see that guy who tell me that is possible. Anyway, I haven't undertood anything.

Comment: No, I insist you´re wrong. You cannot import an executable into your own application and I don´t believe this app does it at all. The solution I gave you at first is the nearest you can do, although my other solution in comments is, probably, what that app does. Anyway, how can you ensure that the machine at video really bypass antivirus? I don´t believe... One thing is run at ADMIN mode and bypass UAC, other is write and create an executable - like a virus would try to do, for instance.

Comment: Just found out that is something that using httpwebrequest to upload and download from his server. You had right, I'm sorry and thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: No problem at all - we are here just to help and (all of us) to learn. PLease vote if you understand I helped you. Good luck.